Error while creating a module in Ceedling in Windows
This is the error that I am facing while creating module or a new project using Ceedling:
:in 'visit_Psych_Nodes_Alias': Alias parsing was not enabled. To enable it, pass 'aliases: true' to 'Psych::load' or 'Psych::safe_load'. (Psych::AliasesNot
How to create a module and a new project folder?

Welcome to SO. Please add your text message directly into the question. And include the complete and exact message. You can use copy&paste to insert as formatted text. No one can copy any part of your picture and put into a search engine etc. Also, are you sure you are using C here? The identifiers look like C++ names.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
